# Is left-shifting a negative value undefined behavior in Rust?

Tags: rust, undefined-behavior

Several operations on integers that yield undefined behavior in C are defined in Rust. A common theme is that they panic in debug mode and have a defined non-panic outcome in release mode. For example, signed integer overflow panics in debug mode, but wraps in release mode. There are also operator variants defined like `wrapping_add()`, `saturating_add()`, etc.

But what about shifting a negative value? This is undefined behavior in C.

The following test case succeeds in Rust 1.17.0:

```
#[test]
fn negative_shift() {
    let i = -128i8;
    let j = i << 1;
    assert_eq!(j, 0);
}
```

Although it succeeds it could still be undefined behavior...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Rust Reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/) has a [list of all undefined behavior](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html). Left shifting a signed number beyond the size of the type is not in the list.